# Como extraer informacion de un archivo de texto

Tags: sed, grep, cut

¿qué tal?

Tengo varios archivos de tablas con la siguiente información, separados por tabulaciones:

```
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinoalloteichus fjordicus ADI127-7    APU14662.1
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinoalloteichus hoggarensis DSM 45943 ASO20105.1
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinoalloteichus sp. AHMU CJ021    AUS77477.1
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinoalloteichus sp. GBA129-24 APU20630.1
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinobacteria bacterium YIM 96077  AYY15149.1
GH5_8   Bacteria    Actinokineospora sp. UTMC 2448  UVS80063.1
```

y me gustaría extraer sólo los códigos de acceso (cuarta columna) y almacenarlos en una lista XXXX de la siguiente forma sin el ".1":

```
APU14662
ASO20105
AUS77477
APU20630
AYY15149
UVS80063
```

¿Cómo puedo configurar el comando? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería funcionar:

```bash
cat archivo.tsv | sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]]+([[:alnum:]]+).1$/\1/'
```

Comment: Saludos, las respuestas que no tienen una explicación son consideradas de baja calidad, recuerda que hay usuarios que podrían tener conocimientos muy básicos y no entenderán tu respuesta, por favor considera agregar una explicación a tu propuesta de solución. ;)